# URL rewriting using old .htaccess rules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am having some real problems with re-writing URLs and any help will be massively appreciated.

I have a php file called `share.php` and an .htaccess file containing the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^share/([^/\.]+)/?$ share.php?variable=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

If I navigate to `domain.com/share/123456`, the `share.php` page is loaded, but there is no value in `$_GET['variable']`.
I have some other rewrite rules in the .htaccess file and I thought that there may be a problem with them, so I removed all of the other rules. One of the rules I removed was `rewriting domain.com/preview` to `domain.com/preview.php`

```
RewriteRule ^preview/?$ preview.php?&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

I then noticed that, even with all of the other rules removed, if I navigated to domain.com/preview, it would still rewrite the URL to preview.php.

So, I removed the .htaccess file completely, restarted Apache, cleared the cache in Firefox and tested it again. Even though the .htaccess file has been deleted, the rules still work.
`domain.com/preview` still redirects to `domain.com/preview.php` and `domain.com/share/123456` still redirects to `domain.com/share.php`(with no data in `$_GET['variable']`).

2 domains point at the server, but there are no rewrite rules in any of the .conf files and there are no longer any .htaccess files. I have tried putting the rewrite rules in the .conf file for the domain instead, but I get the same issue.

Modrewrite is showing as a loaded module if I run `phpinfo()`. Here is my .conf file for the domain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com

    DocumentRoot /home/www/domain.com/public_html
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride All
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've been trying to sort this out all afternoon and I just can't see what's wrong! Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I am really at a loss as to where to start troubleshooting this. I turned on rewrite logging, but nothing comes up in the log files.

I am running Apache 2.4.9 on Ubuntu 12.04 with PHP 5.5.10.

Comment: first , instead of using `&%{QUERY_STRING}` just change the [L] to [L,QSA] and apache will append the query string , second whats with the dot in regex ? did you mean `^share/([^/]+)/?$` instead of `^share/([^/\.]+)/?$` ? if there are only numeric values for share you can also do `^share/([0-9]+)/?$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your domain configuration, the `MultiViews` option of `mod_negotiation` is enabled. The [reference](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews) about that options may be helpful. It does exactly what you describe and what you don't want to happen. Processing of this takes place before evaluating rewrite rules, so it may be related to your problem.

You can disable this behaviour by removing the `MultiViews` option from your domain configuration or by adding the following line to your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

---

Also, you should use the `QSA` flag (for *Query String Append*) instead of appending `%{QUERY_STRING}` manually.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was ready to throw my laptop out of the window! I added the Options -MultiViews into the Directory sections of the domain conf file and replaced the QUERY_STRING with the QSA. Everything works great now :)